# C# - EventHandler is always null

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to implement a very basic EventHandler between a UserControl and a Form. What am I doing wrong with regards to subscribing to the event? No matter what I try, the CreateButtonEvent is always null. I was originally trying to do this between two UserControl classes but decided to use a Form as the subscriber on the assumption that the UserControl subscription may have been the issue. I have also tried using delegates, with no success.

I have viewed and implemented countless solutions to this exact same questions on this site and I still cannot get the Form class to subscribe to the Event within the UserControl class. I am sure it is a very simple mistake that I just cannot pick out. Can anyone give me some insight?

Here is the UserControl class

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SequenceAutomation
{
    public partial class LoginUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler CreateButtonEvent;

        public LoginUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected void gotoCreate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CreateButtonEvent != null)
                CreateButtonEvent(this, e);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("CreateButtonEvent is null");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Form class

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SequenceAutomation
{
    public partial class ApplicationContainer : Form
    {
        private LoginUserControl login = new LoginUserControl();
        private CreateRecUserControl createRec = new CreateRecUserControl();

        public ApplicationContainer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            login.CreateButtonEvent += gotoCreate;
        }

        protected void gotoCreate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            login.Hide();
            createRec.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: from where the methog goToCreate is getting called which  is in your user control?

Comment: no, the event is wired up correctly, based on the code you've shown.  It is strange that `gotoCreate` on `LoginUserControl` looks like an EventHandler in itself.  You'll have to show more code though to get help (like how you show the `LoginUserControl` on your form).

Comment: @Jonesopolis Do you mean a visual representation of the UserControl within the Form?

Comment: Are you sure you are subscribing to the right LoginUserControl?  I wonder if there is another LoginUserControl within your form, maybe defined in ApplicationContainer.Designer.cs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
    private LoginUserControl login = new LoginUserControl();
    private CreateRecUserControl createRec = new CreateRecUserControl();

    public ApplicationContainer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        login.CreateButtonEvent += gotoCreate;
    }
```

You are creating a `LoginUserControl` as a variable in your form and subscribing to it, but you haven't added it to your form anywhere. As in, there is no place where you have `Children.Add(login)`.

I'm guessing you have another copy of the `LoginUserControl` on your form that you placed in the designer, and that's the one that you're interacting with when you run your application. The event is always empty because you've subscribed to that event on a different user control.

Go to the designer, click the user control, go to properties (F4), click the events button, locate the `CreateButtonEvent` and add your `gotoCreate` method.

Then remove the member variable `login` that you've created, because that will just be confusing.

Also, same with `CreateRecUserControl`. If it's not added in the designer, add it in your designer and remove your member variable `createRec`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code exactly and it was OK. I think it could be one of this problems:

- 1: this code is never run:

  ```
       public ApplicationContainer()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       login.CreateButtonEvent += gotoCreate;
   }
  ```
- or 2: you set off the event some where in your code like this:

  login.CreateButtonEvent -= gotoCreate;